# Translating these regexes from javascript to Java

Tags: java, javascript, regex

I've got the regexes working in Javascript, now I want to translate these to Java:

```
            var nat_pattern2 = /^\d{8}$/;
            var nat_pattern2 = /^\d{7}\-\d{1}$/;

            var pct_pattern1 = /^\PCT\/?[A-Z]{2}?\d{4}\/\d{6}$/;
            var ing pct_pattern2 = /^\PCT[A-Z]{2}\d{10}$/;
            var pct_pattern3 = /^\P[A-Z]{2}\d{8}$/;

            var its_pattern1 = /^\ITS\/?[A-Z]{2}?\d{2}\/\d{5}$/;
            var its_pattern2 = /^\ITS[A-Z]{2}\d{7}$/;
            var its_pattern3 = /^\I[A-Z]{2}\d{7}$/;
```

My beginning looks something like this but it is not correct:

`Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("/^\d{8}$/");`

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `/` around your regexp in Java. `\d` as to be escaped in order to be part of the String defining the regex so it will become `\\d`.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\d{8}$");
```

Slashes have no special meanings and so don't need to be escaped too.

```
Pattern natPattern1 = Pattern.compile("^\\d{8}$");
Pattern natPattern2 = Pattern.compile("^\\d{7}-\\d{1}$");

Pattern pctPattern1 = Pattern.compile("^PCT/?[A-Z]{2}?\\d{4}/\\d{6}$");
Pattern pctPattern2 = Pattern.compile("^PCT[A-Z]{2}\\d{10}$");
Pattern pctPattern3 = Pattern.compile("^P[A-Z]{2}\\d{8}$");

Pattern itsPattern1 = Pattern.compile("^ITS/?[A-Z]{2}?\\d{2}/\\d{5}$");
Pattern itsPattern2 = Pattern.compile("^ITS[A-Z]{2}\\d{7}$");
Pattern itsPattern3 = Pattern.compile("^I[A-Z]{2}\\d{7}$");
```

Comment: ...and that means you don't need to escape the slashes inside the regex, too.

Comment: Yes indeed he does not need them.

Comment: Thank you but I'm not sure that these are correct. For instance the string "PCT/SE2012/001083" should match one of these regexes but it doesn't. Could you help me just a little more to verify that these regexes indeed match the same as the javascript regexes I provided. Thanks a lot! I've been working on this for some time now and it's not supposed to be a very difficult problem, just some pattern matching.

Comment: `"PCT/SE2012/001083".matches("^PCT/?[A-Z]{2}?\\d{4}/\\d{6}$")` returns true.

Answer (score 2):

Main points to translate a regex from JS to JAVA:

- No need of surrounding `/`
- Need to escape `\` (e.g. `\\.` instead of `\.`)
- No need to escape `/` (i.e. `\/` becomes `/`)
- No final flags (e.g. `g`, `i`)

You're now able to translate your regexps on your own `;)`

Comment: Instead of final flags, there are parameters to the `compile()` method like `Pattern.DOTALL` for `/i` etc...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've managed to get some results from my regex but the matching is not perfectly the same as it was with the javascript, I think. The word "PCT/SE2012/001083" should match one of the patterns but it doesn't. Could you tell me why? Thanks.

Comment: @NickRosencrantz `"PCT/SE2012/001083".matches("^PCT/?[A-Z]{2}?\\d{4}/\\d{6}$")` returns `true` by me...

Answer (score 1):

The \ is used for escaping in Java-Strings. Therefore you have to escape the . So your String would look like this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\d{8}$");
```

As already stated, the leading and ending / is not needed.

Please note, that if you want to match a \ you have to escape it in your regex. That means you have double escape it in a Java String.
To match \ you have to wire \\ in Java.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer. But why do these pattern don't match: "^PCT/?[A-Z]{2}?\\d{4}/\\d{6}$" should match a string like "PCT/SE2012/001083" should it not? What is the reason that it doesn't match when the javascript version of it does make a match? Is there an incompleteness somewhere?